# Why isn't this sample Electron code working: Loading a markdown file into an editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

My setup

- Win10
- Electron 2.0.1

I'm following an example from the book [Electron in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/electron-in-action) , Chapter 3, where the sample app loads a Markdown file into an Electron editor and shows it in HTML within a dual-pane view.

However, having followed the exact procedure and arrived at the exact same source code at the end of the chapter. I'm seeing nothing the author was trying to show.

Repro:

1. Run the project;
2. Open a .md file;
3. Notice that the two panes are blank.

I'm pretty new to this and fail to see anything useful from the console. So if anyone could code-review the following short listings it'd be much appreciated!

Here is the `main.js`

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');
const fs = require('fs');

let mainWindow = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello from Electron');
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false, // Delay showing window to avoid initial blank.
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
    mainWindow.loadFile('./index.html'); // relpath = same folder as main.js
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
    })
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});

const getFileFromUser = exports.getFileFromUser = () => {
    const files = dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
        properties: ['openFile'],
        filters: [
            { name: 'Text Files', extensions: ['txt'] },
            { name: 'Markdown Files', extensions: ['md', 'markdown'] }
        ]
    });
    if (files) { openFile(files[0]); }
};

const openFile = (file) => {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();
    mainWindow.webContents.send('file-opened', file, content);
}
```

Here is `renderer.js`

```js
const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const mainProcess = remote.require('./main.js'); // plug in main process
const marked = require('marked'); // import marked as marked

// From document(index.html), find and refer to section '#markdown'
const markdownView = document.querySelector('#markdown');
const htmlView = document.querySelector('#html');
const newFileButton = document.querySelector('#new-file');
const openFileButton = document.querySelector('#open-file');
const saveMarkdownButton = document.querySelector('#save-markdown');
const revertButton = document.querySelector('#revert');
const saveHtmlButton = document.querySelector('#save-html');
const showFileButton = document.querySelector('#show-file');
const openInDefaultButton = document.querySelector('#open-in-default');

const renderMarkdownToHtml = (markdown) => {
    htmlView.innerHTML = marked(markdown, { sanitize: true });
};

markdownView.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    const currentContent = event.target.value;
    renderMarkdownToHtml(currentContent);
});

openFileButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    mainProcess.getFileFromUser();
});

ipcRenderer.on('file-opened', (event, file, content) => {
    markdownView.value = content;
    renderMarkdownToHtml(content);
});
```

## UPDATE

I opened the Developer Tool inside the app window and saw this error

```
remote.js:221 Uncaught Error: Could not call remote method 'getFileFromUser'. Check that the method signature is correct. Underlying error: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined
Underlying stack: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:10)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:349:35)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at openFile (path\to\hello_electron\app\main.js:36:24)
    at Object.exports.getFileFromUser (path\to\hello_electron\app\main.js:32:18)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6620:63
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6473:21)

    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6622:17
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6473:21)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:3845:23)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:203:13)
path\to\hello_electron\node_modules\marked\lib\marked.js:1541 marked(): sanitize and sanitizer parameters are deprecated since version 0.7.0, should not be used and will be removed in the future. Read more here: https://marked.js.org/#/USING_ADVANCED.md#options
checkSanitizeDeprecation @ path\to\hello_electron\node_modules\marked\lib\marked.js:1541
```

But looking at the `main.js` code above, I can't find why the path is invalid.

## UPDATE 2

I found that the book sample was expecting a different returned value of `showOpenDialog` from my version.

My API doc says about `showOpenDialog`

```js
/**
     * Resolve with an object containing the following:
     *
     * * `canceled` Boolean - whether or not the dialog was canceled.
     * * `filePaths` String[] - An array of file paths chosen by the user. If the
     * dialog is cancelled this will be an empty array.
     * * `bookmarks` String[] (optional) _macOS_ _mas_ - An array matching the
     * `filePaths` array of base64 encoded strings which contains security scoped
     * bookmark data. `securityScopedBookmarks` must be enabled for this to be
     * populated.
     *
     * The `browserWindow` argument allows the dialog to attach itself to a parent
     * window, making it modal.
     *
     * The `filters` specifies an array of file types that can be displayed or selected
     * when you want to limit the user to a specific type. For example:
     *
     * The `extensions` array should contain extensions without wildcards or dots (e.g.
     * `'png'` is good but `'.png'` and `'*.png'` are bad). To show all files, use the
     * `'*'` wildcard (no other wildcard is supported).
     *
     * **Note:** On Windows and Linux an open dialog can not be both a file selector
     * and a directory selector, so if you set `properties` to `['openFile',
     * 'openDirectory']` on these platforms, a directory selector will be shown.
     */
```

So I switched my code to use `files.filePaths`, but got new errors

```
remote.js:221 Uncaught Error: Could not call remote method 'getFileFromUser'. Check that the method signature is correct. Underlying error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
Underlying stack: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.exports.getFileFromUser (path\to\hello\app\main.js:37:29)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6620:63
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6473:21)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:3845:23)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:203:13)

    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6622:17
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:6473:21)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at WebContents.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:3845:23)
    at WebContents.emit (events.js:203:13)
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved it myself. It seems that the book was using the `showOpenDialog` API according to a wrong/outdated syntax. It is likely that the API used to be synchronous, but later became async by default. I had to replace the sample code

```js
const getFileFromUser = exports.getFileFromUser = () => {
    const files = dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
        properties: ['openFile'],
        filters: [
            { name: 'Text Files', extensions: ['txt'] },
            { name: 'Markdown Files', extensions: ['md', 'markdown'] }
        ]
    });
    if (files) { openFile(files[0]); }
};
```

with an async version

```js
const getFileFromUser = exports.getFileFromUser = () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
        properties: ['openFile'],
        filters: [
            { name: 'Text Files', extensions: ['txt'] },
            { name: 'Markdown Files', extensions: ['md', 'markdown'] }
        ]
    }).then(result => {
        if (result.filePaths.length > 0) { openFile(result.filePaths[0]); }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

Also the returned promise contains more content than the book sample expects.

After this fix, I can see the loaded Markdown file in the panes as expected.